# Moving the position of HTML elements based on the content they have inside (using jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

I have this table:

```
 <table class="wpjb_job_info">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Company Name</b></td>

        <td>English First Tianjin</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Location</b></td>

        <td>Tianjin, China</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Date Posted</b></td>

        <td>Nov 20, 2011</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Category</b></td>

        <td><a href=
        "http://goldstarteachers.com/esl-jobs-in-china/category/eslteacher/">ESL
        Teacher</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Job Type</b></td>

        <td><a href=
        "http://goldstarteachers.com/esl-jobs-in-china/type/full-time/">Full-Time</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Students</b></td>

        <td>Young Learners</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Salary</b></td>

        <td>7,500 - 10,000 RMB / month</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Interviewing</b></td>

        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Contract Length</b></td>

        <td>12 months</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Accommodation</b></td>

        <td>Provided</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Flight Allowance</b></td>

        <td>9,000 RMB</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Holidays</b></td>

        <td>12 days public + 10 days personal</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Insurance</b></td>

        <td>12 months worldwide ERIKA travel, property and health insurance</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Teacher Training</b></td>

        <td>Provided</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Work Visa</b></td>

        <td>Legal Z work visa provided</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

For instance, I would like to make this:

```
  <tr>
    <td><b>Salary</b></td>

    <td>7,500 - 10,000 RMB / month</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><b>Interviewing</b></td>

    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
```

Look like this:

```
      <tr>
        <td><b>Interviewing</b></td>

        <td>Yes</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><b>Salary</b></td>

        <td>7,500 - 10,000 RMB / month</td>
      </tr>
```

with jQuery. In other words, to tell jQuery: move the `tr` that has the text **Interviewing** and move it above the `tr` that has the content **Salary**.  How to accomplish that?

Comment: See the moving elements around section - http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
var interviewing = $('tr > td > b:contains(Interviewing)').closest('tr');
interviewing.insertBefore( interviewing.prev() );
```

or like this:

```
var interviewing = $('tr > td > b:contains(Interviewing)').closest('tr');
interviewing.prev().before( interviewing );
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but the following should work,

```
$('tr:contains("Interviewing")').before( $('tr:contains("Salary")') )
```

or more precisely,

```
$('.wpjb_job_info tr:contains("Interviewing")').before( $('.wpjb_job_info tr:contains("Salary")') )
```